# Notations and definition in an old paper of S Lefschetz

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, homology-cohomology, simplex

I am reading an old short paper of S. Lefschetz

*Lefschetz, S.*, Continuous transformations of manifolds., Nat. Acad. Proc. 9, 90-93 (1923). [ZBL49.0409.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:49.0409.01).

[image]

The above paragraph of the paper is vague to me. what does he mean by $+$ and $-$ signs? In modern Algebraic Topology words, does it mean positive and negative orientation of an oriented $k$-simplex?

In the next paragraph I also don't understand his notations:

[image]

Can you elaborate these by a very simple example?

Comment: This seems to be a discussion of (oriented) intersection theory in differential topology.  I recommend the exposition in Guillemin-Pollack.

Answer (score 0):

The source of such notations and definitions is

*Veblen, Oswald*, The Cambridge Colloquium 1916. Part II: Analysis Situs, Colloquium Publications. American Mathematical Society 5, Part II. New York: American Mathematical Society. VII u. 150 S. (8^0) (1922). [ZBL48.0647.10](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:48.0647.10).